# Slope assertion in Cholesky on digital computers

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, factorization

For a real symmetric positive definite linear system
$$ A \cdot x = b, $$
solved using Choelsky with forward- and backward-substitution, we know it for the numerical approximation $\tilde{x}$ to $x$ the following can be asserted:
$$\exists\ \delta A=\delta A^T \ :\qquad (A + \delta A) \cdot \tilde{x} = b \quad \land \quad \|\delta A\|\leq const \cdot n^2 \cdot \varepsilon_\text{Machine} \cdot \|A\|$$

**Question:** Which assertions hold on $\tilde{x}^T \cdot b$ ?

To clarify: When the Cholesky factor is badly conditioned and we are constrained to single or double IEEE precision, can we be sure that $\tilde{x}^T \cdot b>0$ will actually hold?